# Template class that refers to itself as a template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

This code:

```
template <template <typename> class T>
class A
{
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
    A<B> x;
};
```

doesn't compile, I suppose since `A<B>` is interpreted as `A<B<T> >` within `B`'s scope.

So, how do you pass `B` as a template template parameter within it's scope?

Comment: Doesn't simply specifying following work ? because T can be any type  simple or template type also ...........Code  _--------


template <class T>
class A
{
};

Comment: @Pardeep: I didn't quite follow you. `A`'s T is a template template argument. It's very deifferent from `template <typename T> class A{}`.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to? I've never seen any use for that.

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't do exactly that. This is, however, a minimal code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
    A< ::B > x; // fully qualified name for B
};
```

According to C++ Standard 14.6.1/2 you should use the normal name of the template (i.e., the name from the enclosing scope, not the injected-class-name).

Comment: Nice one :) Worth noting that the space before `::B` is needed, though :)