# Different behavior of compilers - template template argument

Tags: c++

Suppose i have the following code:

```
template <template <typename> class T>
class A {};

template <typename T>
class B
{
    A<B> instance;
};

int main()
{
   B<int> instance;
}
```

gcc 4.7.2 and gcc 4.8.0 compiles this code ok, while icc 13.0.1 and clang 3.2 gave me an error (clang require ::B instead of B, while icc also require whitespace after < in template instantiaion).

Who's right?

I found the thread about it ([Template class that refers to itself as a template template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052415/template-class-that-refers-to-itself-as-a-template-template-parameter)), but i can't understand 14.6.1/2 of the standard and also saw LLVM bug 14350 (http://www.mail-archive.com/llvmbugs@cs.uiuc.edu/msg21095.html). So, clang and intel wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

14.6.1 says:

> The injected-class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a *template-argument-list*, as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself.

The "injected-class-name" is the name of the class template (`B`) "injected" into the scope of the class. In other words, it refers to the use of the unqualified name `B` within the definition of the class `B`. If you use that name in a context where a template name is required: i.e., with explicit template arguments (`B<int>`) or as a template argument for a template which takes a template template parameter (`A<B>`), it should refer to the template itself.

So, gcc is right.

Also, in C++11, you should not need a space after the `<` in `<::B>`. According to section 2.5, paragraph 3, when dividing the input stream into tokens:

> if the next three characters are `<::` and the subsequent character is neither `:` nor `>`, the `<` is treated as a preprocessor token by itself and not as the first character of the alternative token `<:`. (`<:` is another way of writing `[`.)

Comment: Can i use both ::B and B forms in such situation?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov, You can use `::B` when you wish to refer to the template.